# I Installed spinnaker using cloud launcher in GCP with kubernetes enabled but could not find igor.yaml or spinnaker.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, spinnaker, google-kubernetes-engine, spinnaker-halyard

I am installing spinnaker using cloud launcher. I enabled kubernetes. In /opt/config/spinnaker I am not getting any spinnaker-local.yaml or igor.yaml files. How can I integrate Jenkins with spinnaker if I don't see any of the files